# Can I use fresh broccoli in quiche?

Tags: ingredient-selection, broccoli, quiche

I have some (not so) fresh broccoli I need use. I'm thinking of making a quiche with it. Most quiche recipes seem to call for *frozen* broccoli. Can I just use the fresh instead? Does it need any special prep?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can. I do it all the time, in both quiche and omelets. It does need to be cooked which is most easily done in the microwave. Prep by removing much of the large stem, diving into little 'tree' segments, and placing in a microwave-safe dish or bowl. Add just a bit of water, not much, just about a tablespoon, to create steam. Cover with plastic wrap/cling film or a very wet paper towel, and microwave on high for about three minutes. Drain any liquid that remains. It can also be cooked on the stove top, simmered in water, but I prefer to microwave, as it keeps it tender crisp with little loss of nutrients.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go even further - I never cook the broccoli before I use it in a quiche.

It is all about the size of broccoli you use: large chunk = long cooking time, small chunks = short cooking time. For a finely chopped broccoli I would go for 30-40 min in 180C.

So all you have to do is finely chop the broccoli before you use it in a quiche. You can do it either by hand or with a food processor.

P.S - I just made a cauliflower quiche the same way yesterday. Went out great and soft.